# Error on deploying Vmware Integrated Openstack 3.0.0 on vSphere 6.0

Tags: vmware, openstack, vsphere, esx

I am trying to install VMware Integrated Openstack 3.0.0.0-4345506_OVF10.ova through vSphere client.

But as soon as i load the ovf its giving me the below error:

**This OVF package uses features that are not supported when deploying directly to and ESX Host**

**Line 267: Unsupported section 'vServiceDependencySection'(A vService Dependency).**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWT61.png)

Please check the screenshot for the error.

Please help me here,what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have vCenter server and deploy this ova through web client.